# Create a calendar based on a list from another site

Tags: list, sharepoint-calendar

I have a Sharepoint list which contains the list of holidays in a calender year.  I would like to use this list Information for the calendar which I have. Kindly suggest ways to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a designer workflow to write the relevant calendar info to the calendar list.

Comment: You mean to create a Workflow to copy the contents from the SharePoint List to the SharePoint Calendar?